# Im tyring to make an Alexa skill and its not working with the API. What am i doing wrong (python)

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

Im trying to make an Alexa Skill that calls to an API and gives some general information on the Coronavirus. Why i get to this intent it stops working. I tried commenting out the API stuff, and making write a simple Hello World and that worked. However the API part still doesn't and i cant figure out why. I imported the same libraries, copy pasted it in Mu-code, changed speak_output to print and it worked.

Heres the intent with the API.

```
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("GlobalInfoIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_data = response.json()
       # print(data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"])
        speak_output = (json_data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"])

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )
```

Heres my full code.

````
# This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Python.
# Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
# session persistence, api calls, and more.
# This sample is built using the handler classes approach in skill builder.
import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils
import requests
import json
from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput

from ask_sdk_model import Response

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Welcome, you can say Global Summary or the two letter country code?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class GlobalInfoIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("GlobalInfoIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary"
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_data = response.json()
       # print(data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"])
        speak_output = (json_data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"])

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class HelpIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.HelpIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "You can say hello to me! How can I help?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class CancelOrStopIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Cancel and Stop Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
                ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Goodbye!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class SessionEndedRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Session End."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("SessionEndedRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        # Any cleanup logic goes here.

        return handler_input.response_builder.response


class IntentReflectorHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
    It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
    for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
    handler chain below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("IntentRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        intent_name = ask_utils.get_intent_name(handler_input)
        speak_output = "You just triggered " + intent_name + "."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler):
    """Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
    stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
    the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> bool
        return True

    def handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> Response
        logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)

        speak_output = "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )

# The SkillBuilder object acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
# payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
# defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.


sb = SkillBuilder()

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(GlobalInfoIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelpIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(CancelOrStopIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(SessionEndedRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(IntentReflectorHandler()) # make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers

sb.add_exception_handler(CatchAllExceptionHandler())

lambda_handler = sb.lambda_handler()```
````

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you've copy/pasted your code, as your print statement would actually error (should be `json_data` not `data`). That said, the code you've provided looks good.

My guess would be that `speak_output` contains some unsafe characters.

Easiest test would be to try outputting simpler (known) copy. Set `speak_output = "hello world"`. If that works, as I'm guessing it will, it's your API copy.

Next, `import html`, then escape your API copy...

```
        speak_output = html.escape(json_data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"])
```

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/build-responses.html#responsebuilder (scroll down to the note)

Comment: The docs reference an SsmlUtils helper, but that doesn't appear to exist in the python SDK.

Comment: I did what you told me, it work with hello world. So i tested a different api and it worked. This json file only had some data in it and didnt break down into subcategories. When i tried another that goes from one main category, like global, to another i wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

please convert it to string.
here **"NewConfirmed"** is in integer. so you need to convert it.

```
speak_output = str((json_data["Global"]["NewConfirmed"]))
```